# How to count by referring date in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, window-functions

I have tables like following.

`table`

```
product   customer  surrender_date
A            a       2020/5/1
B            a       2020/6/1
C            b       2019/7/1
D            b       2020/8/1
E            b       2020/9/1
```

First I'd like to `group` by `customer`

```
product   customer  surrender_date
A            a       2020/5/1
B            a       2020/6/1
```

Second I'd like to `rank` by refferring to `surrender_date` from the `newest`one

My desired result is like following

```
product   customer  surrender_date  rank
A            a       2020/5/1        2
B            a       2020/6/1        1
```

Therefore My whole desired result is following.

```
product   customer  surrender_date  rank
A            a       2020/5/1        2
B            a       2020/6/1        1
C            b       2019/7/1        3
D            b       2020/8/1        2
E            b       2020/9/1        1
```

Are there any way to achieve this?

As I've never referred to `date`, If someone has opinion,please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select
    t.*,
    row_number() over(partition by customer order by surrender_date desc) rnk
from mytable
```

Notes:

- I don't see what the question has to do with aggregation
- depending on how you want to handle ties, you might be looking for `rank()` or `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`